# Get indexes of unique values in column (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I need to get row numbers with unique values in `x`. I've come to the following solution:

```
x = pv.index.get_level_values("Код") #get index level values
dups = x[x.duplicated()].unique() #get dup. values
uniques = x[~x.isin(dups)] #get not dup. values
uniques_indexes = np.where(x.isin(uniques))[0].tolist()
```

I think there's too much calculations. Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)
index = np.random.choice('A B C D E F G'.split(), 10)
pv = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10), index=index, columns=['value'])

Out[60]: 
    value
A -0.2347
A -1.4397
D  0.4328
A  2.3045
C -0.1226
G  0.0155
E  0.2660
C -0.1138
F  1.0111
C -1.4408

# reset_index first to preserve the line number
pv.reset_index(inplace=True)

Out[128]: 
  index   value
0     A -0.2347
1     A -1.4397
2     D  0.4328
3     A  2.3045
4     C -0.1226
5     G  0.0155
6     E  0.2660
7     C -0.1138
8     F  1.0111
9     C -1.4408

# replace your groupby index level
pv.sort_index().groupby('index').filter(lambda group: len(group) == 1)


Out[129]: 
  index   value
2     D  0.4328
5     G  0.0155
6     E  0.2660
8     F  1.0111
```

Comment: But i need line numbers in the original dataframe, not a new filtered dataframe. (Then i'll decorate these lines in Excel)

Comment: just modified (add a `reset_index` step) to keep the line number as well.

Comment: Thanks! `pv.reset_index().groupby("Код").filter(lambda g: len(g)==1).index.values` returns numpy array