# Pandas dataframe: change unique values in each column to NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` arranged in a manner similar to this:

```
ID   Sample_1   Sample_2
A    0.182      0.754
B    0.182      0.754
C    0.182      0.01
D    0.182      0.2
E    0.9        0.2
```

As you can see, there are some repeated values ("true" measurements) and single values (that are actually "bad" measurements). What I need to do is to replace all unique values (that are so-called "bad") with NAs. This needs to be done for all columns.

In other words, the final dataframe should look like this:

```
ID   Sample_1   Sample_2
A    0.182      0.754
B    0.182      0.754
C    0.182      NaN
D    0.182      0.2
E    NaN        0.2
```

A possible solution I've thought about involves `groupby` and `filter` to get the index values (like in [Get indexes of unique values in column (pandas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049111/get-indexes-of-unique-values-in-column-pandas)) and then replace the values, but the issue is that it works only for one column at a time:

```
unique_loc = df.groupby("Sample_1").filter(lambda x: len(x) == 1).index
df.loc[unique_loc, "Sample_1"] = np.nan
```

This means it would need to get repeated for many columns (and I have many in the actual data). Is there a more efficient solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) for set `NaN`s with mask created by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) per columns in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), for selecting all columns without first is used [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.iloc[:, 1:]=df.iloc[:, 1:].where(df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(lambda x:x.duplicated(keep=False)))
print (df)
  ID  Sample_1  Sample_2
0  A     0.182     0.754
1  B     0.182     0.754
2  C     0.182       NaN
3  D     0.182     0.200
4  E       NaN     0.200
```

If `ID` is index:

```
df = df.set_index('ID')

df = df.where(df.apply(lambda x: x.duplicated(keep=False)))
print (df)
    Sample_1  Sample_2
ID                    
A      0.182     0.754
B      0.182     0.754
C      0.182       NaN
D      0.182     0.200
E        NaN     0.200
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to get the values via `np.unique`, and replace them with `pd.DataFrame.mask`:

```py
arr, counts = np.unique(df.filter(like='Sample').to_numpy(), return_counts=True)
df.mask(df.isin(arr[counts==1]))

  ID  Sample_1  Sample_2
0  A     0.182     0.754
1  B     0.182     0.754
2  C     0.182       NaN
3  D     0.182     0.200
4  E       NaN     0.200
```

Comment: +1 but doesn't take columns separately into account but maybe doable with some reshaping on the numpy array

Comment: since OP wants it across the dataframe, there is no need for individual column check - that's my understanding though of the question

Comment: maybe. from their attempt and desire to repeat for each column, i understood otherwise but not so important.